# Finding nonzero Fourier terms of a function in $L_2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $x(t) = \cosh(t)$ and the basis $B = \{1,t,t^2, ...\}$
I know $c_k = \frac{\langle x,e_k \rangle}{\lVert e_k \rVert ^2} $ so I attempted to find the coefficients:

> $c_0 = \frac{\langle x,e_0 \rangle}{\lVert e_0 \rVert ^2} = \frac{\langle \cosh(t), 1 \rangle}{\lVert 1 \rVert ^2} = \frac{\int_0^1\cosh(t)dt}{1} = sinh(1)$ 
>   $c_1 = \frac{\langle x,e_1 \rangle}{\lVert e_1 \rVert ^2}  = \frac{\langle \cosh(t), t \rangle}{\lVert t \rVert ^2} = \frac{\int_0^1\cosh(t)tdt}{\lVert t \rVert ^2} = \frac{1-e^{-1}}{\lVert t \rVert ^2}$ **What is $\lVert t \rVert ^2$?  Is it just $t^2$ or do I leave it as $\lVert t \rVert ^2?$** 
>   $c_2 = \frac{\langle x,e_2 \rangle}{\lVert e_2 \rVert ^2}  = \frac{\langle \cosh(t), t^2 \rangle}{\lVert t^2 \rVert ^2} = \frac{\int_0^1\cosh(t)t^2dt}{\lVert t^2 \rVert ^2} = \frac{e^2-5}{2e\lVert t^2 \rVert ^2}$  **Again, what is ${\lVert t^2 \rVert ^2}$?**

From here I just plug these coefficients into $\sum c_ke_k$ to get the terms.  Is what I have done here correct?

Comment: What is the question? The basis is not orthogonal with that inner product, so you will not get Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @copper.hat so how do I go about finding the Fourier coefficients? I only need to find the first 3 terms of the series.  My original question was basically is that right and how/if I should simplify $\lVert t^2 \rVert^2$?

Comment: If you are asking for the power series expansion of $x$ you just have to use the series for the exponential function. There is no such thing as Fourier terms with respect to $\{1,t,t^{2},...\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy maybe I made a mistake in understanding the problem, but it says "find the first 3 nonzero terms in the fourier series for $x(t)=cosh(t) \in L_2(0,1)$, if the linearly independent basis is formed by the polynomials $p_1(t) = 1, p_2(t) = t, p_3(t) = t^3$."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have never seen anybody talking about Fourier series with respect to functions like $1,t,t^{2},...$ which are not orthonormal. Can you tell us where you found this question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Its just a homework question my professor wrote

Comment: A Fourier series is an expansion (in $L^2$) with respect to an orthogonal basis. (The usual suspects are $e_n(t) = e^{i 2\pi n t}$), but any (Schauder) basis will suffice. You could use Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation on the basis $t \mapsto t^k$ (cf. Legendre polynomials) to get an orthonormal basis $b_k$ which you can them use in the usual way to obtain Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @copper.hat I got an orthogonal basis and was able to find the Fourier coefficients, but for the life of me I can't find the formula to plug them into.  Is the answer just $c_0e_0 + c_1e_1 + c_2e_2 + ...$?

Comment: @VinnyChase: In general, if you have a basis $b_k$ (Schauder or otherwise), and you compute the coefficients $c_k$  of some point $f$ with respect to the basis, then $f = \sum_k c_k b_k$.

Comment: @VinnyChase: I didn't pay enough attention to the question. There is an easier way, sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach would be to use Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation to the basis $t \mapsto t^k$. In this case, this would generate the shifted Legendre polynomials $P_k$ (look for shifted in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) and then one would find the Fourier coefficients with respect to this Schauder basis using the formula for
$c_k$ above.

However, in this example, there is a simple approach using the fact that the Fourier coefficients are unique.

Since $\cosh t = 1 + {t^2 \over 2!} + {t^4 \over 4!}+ \cdots$, we can read off the coefficients as $c_0 = 1, c_1 = 0, c_2={1 \over 2!}$, etc.